# Pseudo random number generator in python

Tags: python, random

I tried to perform the following code using python:

[image]

My code is:

```
#UNIFORM RANDOM SAMPLING 

import numpy as np                #library needed for numerical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #library needed for plotting purposes
from time import process_time     #function needed for checking CPU time
from scipy.stats import chisquare #function needed for chi square test

#*******************************************************************************

i=np.uintc(987654321)              #unsigned int variable i with seed 987654321

r=2**30                            #range of the sequence

t1_start=process_time()            #process start time 

for count in range(r):             #for cycle over expected period and update i

    i=np.uintc(i*663608941)

t1_stop=process_time()             #process stop time
    
print("\nLoop stopped at the element:", i, ".\n")     
print("Is this the last element of the series? 1 for YES other numbers for NO", i/987654321,".\n")
print("The CPU time needed in order to take to go throught the whole sequence is", t1_stop-t1_start, "seconds.\n")
```

Meanwhile the output:

[image]

As you can see, the programm woks, but is not very optimized ( almost 1 hour of run).

How can I optimize it and obtain the desired output in many seconds?

Comment: I do not think there is too much space to optimize. How about `987654321*pow(663608941, 2**30, 0xFFFFFFFF)`?

Comment: Works, thanks! But  I don't understand, what it is 0xFFFFFFF?

Comment: @J.Snowden It's incorrect. Should be `1<<32` for exponentiation mod 2^32 (the size of an unsigned int). The result is the same (because `pow(663608941, 2**30, 1<<32)==1`), but as I mentioned below, this doesn't check for the existence of shorter loops in the sequence.

Comment: It is essentially `987654321* 663608941^(2**30) % 0xFFFFFFFF)`. `0xFFFFFFFF` is the maximum value of 32-bit integer. `mod 0xFFFFFFFF` is meant to simulate the arithmetic operations on 32-bit integer. The `pow` function uses a modular exponentiation algorithm internally, which is more efficient than the straightforward iteration algorithm. But as @r3mainer said, it does not check for shorter sequence length. So it might be off the point of the problem description.

Comment: @Dummmy No, 32-bit arithmetic is performed modulo 2^32 (0x100000000), not 2^32-1 (0xffffffff). You're off by one.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. So there is not a way to make the code efficient without running two loops, one for checking the sequence and another on the entire sequence?

Comment: @r3mainer You are right. Thanks for pointing that out. It should be `987654321*pow(663608941, 2**30, 1<<32)`.

Comment: The problem looks like some sort of invitation to the 2,000 years old, recursive [Indian Exponentiation Algorithm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107708/origin-of-square-and-multiply-algorithm). The algorithm operates in O(log n) time rather than O(n), n being the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *have* to use Python?

The code will run much faster in C. When compiled with `-O3` optimization, this takes about a second to run on my desktop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t i, n;
    i = 987654321;
    n = 0;
    while (1) {
        n++;
        i *= 663608941;
        if (i == 987654321) break;
    }
    printf("Sequence repeats after %" PRIu32 " iterations.\n", n);
    printf("Expected value: %d.\n", 1<<30);
    return 0;
}
```

I should also point out that your code isn't strictly correct. It confirms that the sequence returns to its initial state after 2<sup>30</sup> iterations, but doesn't check for other occurrences of i=987654321 during the loop.

---

If you're stuck using Python, it looks like numpy's integer types don't offer much of an advantage in terms of speed. The following code runs in about 200 seconds on my machine.:

```
def seq_check():
    x = 987654321
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        x = (x * 663608941) & 0xffffffff
        if x == 987654321:
            break
    return n
```

Comment: I'm agree with your comment, you are right. Yes, i nedd to use Python, thanks.

Comment: I don't know why but in my machine the code does't work, return x=x and n=1000000.

Comment: That makes no sense. How can it return two values? If you just print the return value from this function (i.e., `print(seq_check())`), it should say 1073741824.

Comment: Sorry, was my fault. The code runs in 6 minutes using Google colab.

Comment: I'm also trying to check the CPU time putting before the ```def seq_check()``` and after it the line ```t1_start=process_time()``` and ```t1_stop=process_time()``` respectly. But it return a fals CPU time, about 1e-5.